# Syntax question, how can I add a string to an argument in a function?

Tags: python, string, function

I am trying to add a period after the end of the 'names' argument I have in my function. I would like the output to be 'Hello Henry. How are you?' Is there a way that I can add one? I would like it to be built into the function itself so that any name that goes in will have period after.

```
def greet(name, message):
    print('Hello', name, message)

greet('Henry', 'How are you?')
greet(name='Jill', message='Sup?')
```

Comment: is this by any chance, python?

Comment: Did you try: `print('Hello ', name, '. ', message, sep='')`

Comment: is this python 3.6+ by chance?

Answer (score 1):

Use `format` for cleaner outputs

```py
def greet(name, message):
    print("Hello {}. {}".format(name, message))
```

Makes it more readable

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve it using python `f` strings:

```
def greet(name, message):
    print(f'Hello {name}. {message}')

greet('Henry', 'How are you?')
greet(name='Jill', message='Sup?')
```

Output:

```
Hello Henry. How are you?
Hello Jill. Sup?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write `greet()` as follows:

```
def greet(name, message):
    print('Hello', name + '.', message)
```